# Adding default value(containing a -(hyphen)) to a docker-compose variable if an env. variable is not set

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have some problem in setting default value in my docker-compose.yml file
In my docker-compose.yml file I have configuration for zookeeper as

```yaml
  order-zookeeper:
    image: <some-image>
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: x-zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2222:2222"
      - "8888:8888"
      - "3333:3333"
    extra_hosts:
      - "kafka-1:${SOME_IP}"
    networks: [ some-network ]
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_PEER_PORT: 2222
      <some-more configs here>
```

If the value of SOME_IP is not present, I want to set it to a default value of `host-gateway`. Is it possible to do that?

I tried `"kafka-1:${SOME_IP:#{host-gateway}}"` and `"kafka-1:${SOME_IP:-host-gateway}"` Both the strategies did not work out.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Since afaik, the functionality used inject the default value is [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), I think it is not possible to include a hyphen in the value to be inserted as replacement. See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122845/using-a-b-for-variable-assignment-in-scripts

Comment: I'd expect the second form to work; see the Compose [Variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution) documentation.  Compose doesn't run a shell _per se_, but in either case I don't think the second hyphen would have any special meaning.